# Php undefined index error when I upload a file

Tags: php, upload

```
      <form method="post" action="" enctype="multypart/form-data">
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:70px">
        <p>Carousel Number</p>
          <select name="carousel_num">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="2">3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="pic">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
      </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $carousel_num = $_POST["carousel_num"];
  $tmpname = $_FILES["pic"]['tmp_name'];
  $filename = $_FILES["pic"]['name'];
  $file_ext_arr = explode(".",$filename);
  $file_name = $file_ext_arr[0];
  $ext = end($file_ext_arr);
  if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "gif"){
    move_uploaded_file("Carousel_$carousel_num","./upload/".$ext);
    echo "<script>history.go(-1);</script>";
  }else{
    echo "<script>alert(\"only 'jpg, png, jpeg, gif' file is permitted.\");history.back(-1);</script>";
  }
}
?>
```

Hi guys, This code make an error

`Notice: Undefined index: pic in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/astral/special.php on line 49`

like this. I think, there is no spelling mistake. I don't know what Should I do to make it work.

Please help me!!

Comment: See my answer hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

It should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: @OhHyeonJun Great to help you accept my answer if it helps you to say to others yours is solved

Answer (score 1):

It is not `enctype='multypart/form-data'`. The correct one is `enctype='multipart/form-data'`.

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: i think both are same :) , i mean to say .. what you have type " It is not enctype='multipart/form-data'. The correct one is enctype='multipart/form-data' "

Comment: your answer is the same to mine

Comment: Ok you changed now .. :)

Comment: @JohnRobertson..ohh John I was typing my answer at that time. I saw your answer only after I submitted my answer. Sorry.

Comment: @user3209031..It was a typo.